# Google App Engine Python: get image upload size server-side

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine

I am building a Google App Engine App that lets users upload images; I have everything working fine, but I am struggling to find a way to ensure that the user does not upload an image too large (because I am resizing the images, so this crashes my python script).
When a user uploads a large image, I get this error

```
RequestTooLargeError: The request to API call images.Transform() was too large.
```

I know that there is a size limitation on what GAE allows for it's image API, I am just trying to find a way to deal with this server side; something along the lines of

```
if (image is too large):
    inform user
else:
    proceed
```

I haven't had any luck finding the right python code to do this; can anyone help me out?

Comment: well what type of objects/types does your Transform method take?

Comment: Sorry, I don't exactly understand your question; I am taking the input from an HTML form, file input, with enctype=multipart/form-data, and trying to send that data to the Google images API.  I am just trying to verify how large that data is before I send it to Google and I get the exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from google.appengine.runtime import apiproxy_errors

...

try:
    #the code you are getting the error at
except apiproxy_errors.RequestTooLargeError, message:
    print message # or something else
```

Comment: Perfect, that's just what I was looking for.  I tried all sorts of those Try-Excepts, but I was missing that import statement, so I couldn't even compile while referencing the RequestTooLargeEror.
Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm pretty sure I had to search through the appengine source code to find where this error was declared after I first encountered it. Glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your problem completely but maybe a try would work?

```
try:    
    images.Transform()
except Transform.RequestTooLargeError:
    inform
else:
    proceed
```

Comment: Yup, thats what I was looking for, I was just missing the appropriate way to reference the RequestTooLargeError (see above answer from bboe).  Thanks for your help!